# Mongoose save method seems to not be working

Tags: mongodb, rest, mongoose

I am trying to create a REST API. I am pretty new to the back end and am just practicing on my own for the time being. For my code, I know it's bad practice to store the plain text password but again, this is completely for practice and will never go live. I will also add encryption at a later point for practice.

My issue is I am not sure why my API does not work. I see where it fails, it fails in the catch block when I try to save a user but I do not get any error to tell me what is wrong exactly, besides the once I force. I have another part on this website that follows almost the exact same logic and it works perfectly but for this one it does not. I have no idea how to solve my issue but after googling I still cannot figure it out. It looks perfectly fine too me, but as mentioned I am pretty new to the backend.

This is my controller function:

```
const signup = async (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req); 
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return next(new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data', 422));
    }

    const { name, email, password, places } = req.body;

    let existingUser;
    try {
        existingUser = await User.findOne({email: email}) // finds one document matching our criteria we set
    } catch(err) {
        const error = new HttpError('Signing up failed, please try again later', 500);
        return next(error);
    }
    
    if (existingUser) {
        const error = new HttpError('User exists already, please login instead', 422);
        return next(error);
    }

    const createdUser = new User({
        name,
        email,
        image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels-photo-220453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260',
        password,
        places
    });
    
    try {
        await createdUser.save();
    } catch(err) {
        const error = new HttpError(
            'Signing up failed', 500
        );
        return next(error);
    }

    res.status(201).json({user: createdUser.toObject({ getters:true })});

};
```

I use Postman to send the request to my API endpoint with all of the correct information. Based on what I recieve back it is failing in the try catch block of `await createdUser.save()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this from google this was my solution:

First I suggest you add this into your save method to try and diagnose the problem

```
await createdUser.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
        });
```

This help me greatly as it gave me more information on how to solve it.It turns out my problem was because I misspelled a field in my Schema. So extremely simple solution!